# Есть 2 xlsx файла с одинаковой структурой. Нужно спарсить оба на Python и изменения внести в БД MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, парсер, логирование, xlsx

уважаемое комьюнити. Есть задача, надеюсь на ваши советы!

Есть 2 xlsx файла с одинаковой структурой. Нужно спарсить оба на Python и изменения внести в БД MySQL. То, что с желтым фоном это коллекция, под ней идут предметы входящие в нее они могут меняться, добавляться и удаляться.

Механизм работы такой, есть рабочий файл, он каждый раз заменяется на новый, а старый перемещается в архив. Нужно логировать удаление старых,изменения текущих и добавление новых коллекции и предметов в БД для последующего вывода на сайте.

Если в новом файле строка изменена или она есть в новом файле и нет в старом, и наоборот - эту строку нужно записать в формате было/стало или просто с информацией о добавлении и удалении.

**Добавлю, что данные файла до текущей задачи просто парсились и добавлялись в таблицу перед этим она полностью очищалась. Все это происходит с помощью Cron'а на сервере, поэтому нужны варианты без личного вмешательства в будущем.**

Как это можно сделать лучше? [image: Структура файла]
[image: В базе данных так выглядит]

Так выглядит в БД. Логи будут в отдельной таблице

Comment: Добавлю, что с самим парсингом проблем нету. Сложность появляется в работе с данными, с правильным отбором информации и анализом

Comment: А питон-то тут зачем? сохранить в CSV, залить на сервер и там обработать...

Comment: Конкретно этот файл уже обрабатывался на Питоне и для него уже был написан скрипт, мне нужно лишь доработать его.

Comment: Ну дело ваше... покажите пример: таблица на сервере (2-3 строки), таблица изменений (4-5 строк, чтобы присутствовали все возможные варианты), конечное состояние. В виде форматированной текстовой таблицы, а не скриншотами.

Comment: Я не совсем понял, как вам предоставить это)

Comment: Наберите в окне ввода таблицу, форматированную пробелами, а потом перед и после добавьте по строке, в которой набейте только три бэктика (это обратная кавычка, где русская Ё). В тексте вопроса, само собой.

Comment: *Так выглядит в БД.* Какое выражение (комбинация полей) идентифицирует соответствие? `Коллекция <-> collection`?

Comment: Вы помогли мне с идей с базой данных. Поскольку они у меня есть уже в базе данных и записей там не так много(500) и вряд ли будет сильно больше, то я буду просто посылать запросы в базу данных, если будет возвращать что-то, то буду делать проверку на изменение данных, а после удалять, если будет пустота, то значит эта запись новая и я буду сразу в лог её записывать. По окончании проверки данных из нового файла буду запрашивать все записи и если они остались, то я буду сразу записывать их в лог и подписывать, как удаленные. А после буду просто перезаписывать эту таблицу новыми данными.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, исходное состояние - это файл считан питоном, распарсен и хранится в некоем виде, который соответствует показанной таблице.

Далее:

1. Загружаем эти данные на MySQL в новую таблицу:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tmp LIKE main;
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (массив данных);
```

2. Обрабатываем и пишем логи:

```sql
INSERT INTO log
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', 'Добавление', collection, category, exclusion)
FROM tmp
LEFT JOIN main USING (collection)
WHERE main.collection IS NULL;

INSERT INTO log
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', 'Удаление', collection, category, exclusion)
FROM main
LEFT JOIN tmp USING (collection)
WHERE tmp.collection IS NULL;

INSERT INTO log
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', 'Изменение', collection, main.category, tmp.category, main.exclusion, tmp.exclusion)
FROM main
JOIN tmp USING (collection);
```

3. Заменяем старую таблицу на актуальную:

```sql
RENAME TABLE main TO temp;
RENAME TABLE tmp TO main;
DROP TABLE temp;
```

И, собственно, всё...

Питон обеспечивает руление этим процессом - передаёт запросы (на этапе 1 - и данные), отслеживает выполнение и регистрирует ошибки/предупреждения, при ошибках обрывает процесс и зовёт оператора.